# How to resolve GraphResponse: Unsupported get request

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

Full Error code: GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID '*************' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}

I am trying to embed the facebook login in my android app. I have followed the QuickStart at facebook developers website to try and embed it. 
The problem is that when I run my app, when it boots I get the error listed in the title. And when I click the button nothing happens. Find the attached code.

```
loginButton.setPermissions(Arrays.asList(EMAIL));
    // If you are using in a fragment, call loginButton.setFragment(this);

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }


    });

    AccessTokenTracker tokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
    @Override
    protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken accessToken, AccessToken accessToken1) {
        auth.loadUserProfile(accessToken1);
    }
};

    public void loadUserProfile(AccessToken accessToken)
{
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
            try {
                String email = object.getString("email");

                System.out.println(email);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    Bundle pararmeters = new Bundle();
    pararmeters.putString("fields", "email");
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Above is my code

Comment: How you fix it?

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You Code is missing with the callback function in the onActivityResult

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        mcallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call before  **setAutoLogAppEventsEnabled(true);** before registerCallback and set it again
to **false** when data is received  from facebook

Answer (score 0):

I just got rid of this error, actually I was doing a mistake , when I was giving setPermission in that I was assigning wrong access permission. So, just check that permission carefully
like here

*log_btn.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","user_birthday"));*

you can also check on developer page in ***app review section permission and features***